# MVC 5 IIS; Using machine.config prior to web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, web-config, asp.net-membership

I am trying to deploy an MVC5 Website to an IIS7 Server. The Website uses an Asp.net Membership.

When trying to connect to my SQlServer, the Website is trying to use the machine.config connectionstring "LocalSqlServer".

But I did not specify to use this ConnectionString. How do I change this behaviour, so it uses the given connectionString in the web.config instead of the machine.cofnig.

```
  public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("XXXXMembership", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
        }
```

Web.Config :

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="XXXXMembership" connectionString="Data Source=xxxxxxxx;Initial Catalog=xxxxx;user id=xxxxx;password=xxxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to the top of your `<connectionStrings>` section

```
<connectionStrings>
    <clear />
    <remove name="LocalSqlServer" />
    <add name="XXXXMembership" connectionString="Data Source=xxxxxxxx;Initial Catalog=xxxxx;user id=xxxxx;password=xxxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Tried this. Nothing changes.

Comment: Is that your only DBContext?

Comment: After Adding your Solution and Adding this to my LocalWebConfig. It works.

Answer (score 1):

When you publish the application, make sure you change what database to use in the Wizard. 
[image: Database Connection String Settings on Publish]

Comment: That got me once. Spent all day trying to figure out why my prod code was hitting my dev database lol

Answer (score 1):

@stevenackley After Adding your Solution and Adding this to my LocalWebConfig. It works.

```
<membership>
      <providers>
       <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" connectionStringName="XXXMembership" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" applicationName="/" requiresUniqueEmail="false" passwordFormat="Hashed" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="7" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1" passwordAttemptWindow="10" passwordStrengthRegularExpression="" />
        <add name="MySQLMembershipProvider" type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLMembershipProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.5.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" applicationName="/" requiresUniqueEmail="false" passwordFormat="Clear" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="7" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1" passwordAttemptWindow="10" passwordStrengthRegularExpression="" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <profile>
      <providers>
       <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="XXXMembership" applicationName="/" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
        <add name="MySQLProfileProvider" type="MySql.Web.Profile.MySQLProfileProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.5.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </profile>
    <roleManager>
      <providers>
       <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="XXXMembership" applicationName="/" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
        <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
        <add name="MySQLRoleProvider" type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLRoleProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.5.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
```